# Django crispy forms tabholder can't change css

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

In my form i would like to change the style of the tabs, if i add a css_class to TabHolder it won't render it, it just keeps the default class. Here is the **init** of the modelform.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        TabHolder(
            Tab(_('Company'),
                'name',
                css_class='nav-item active'),
            Tab('Address',
                'country',
                css_class='nav-item'),
            Tab('Info',
                'email', 'phone', 'website',
                css_class='nav-item'),
            css_class='nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-highlight nav-justified mb-0'
        ),
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('submit', "Submit form", css_class='btn btn-primary')
        ),
    )
```

As you can see in TabHolder there is css_class='nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-highlight nav-justified mb-0' but it keeps showing just css_class='nav nav-tabs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS_class is hard coded in the tab template. Easiest fix is probably to over ride the template.

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/layout/tab.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I thought it would be better to solve it in another way.
I preferred a less invasive approach.
I used a javascript inside my template, which adjusts the element class.
Just add the code above in your template.

```
    <script>
        function load() {
            document.getElementById('tab-content').getElementsByClassName('nav nav-tabs')[0].className = "nav nav-tabs bg-nav-pills nav-justified mb-3";
        }
        window.onload = load;
    </script>
```